# Past-perfect tense

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-perfect

Consider the following question:

> Monica had dinner at home. She ______ dinner when she ______ home.
>
> (a) ate, came
>
> (b) had eaten, had come
>
> (c) had eaten, came
>
> (d) ate, had come

According to me answer to the above question should be option (d), as first she came home and then she ate dinner, using present perfect. But the correct answer is (a). How is it possible, as using the option (a), no time order of activity is preserved?

Comment: The title of the OP should be in the form of a question.

Comment: Logically (d) might seem to be the right answer, but in real life people say "I did X when I got home" without feeling it necessary to specify that the arrival at home came first. Option (c), however, implies that Monica had eaten somewhere else before coming home.